# MVC 4 Razor - JQuery UI Autocomplete partially stopped working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In the project I'm working on, I have an MVC 4 Web App set up with its database back end. Almost from the beginning, I had gotten autocomplete working with JQuery UI. Everything was working out perfectly. I updated versions of JQuery UI a couple times, but it worked fine with each upgrade. The version I have right now is 1.11.2.

Today, though, I shifted around what areas a form covered, since it was including things that it didn't necessarily need. The autocomplete boxes I had didn't need to be in the form anymore, so they were shifted out. There was nothing else done to the autocomplete boxes.
For some reason, the autocomplete formatting is now broken and one of the boxes won't even return anything. The one that's still partially working, is pulling out the correct "value", but the "label" is the one not showing up like it had before. The completely broken one isn't showing either one of them.
The script for the autocompletes are just inside of a normal script tag at the bottom of the view page, but not inside of an @section or anything.

Here's the autocomplete code for the one that is half working:

```
$("#agencyCode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employee/LookupAgencies",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Code + " - " + item.Name, value: item.Code, desc: item.Name, parent: item.ParentID };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event,ui){
            document.getElementById('agencyChoice').innerHTML = ui.item.desc;
        }
    });
```

And this is the one that is completely broken:

```
$("#fOOCTTaxCode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employee/LookupFOOCT",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FederalTaxID + " - " + item.Name, value: item.FederalTaxID, desc: item.Name };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            document.getElementById('fooctChoice').innerHTML = ui.item.desc;
        }
    });
```

The back end part that is querying the database to get the results for the autocomplete look like this:

```
public ActionResult LookupAgencies(string term)
    {
        int currentCampaign = ePledgeDataLayer.Campaign.GetCurrentCampaign();

        var retValue = (from r in ePledgeDataLayer.Organization.GetAgencies(currentCampaign)
                        where r.Code.Contains(term)
                        select new { r.Code, r.Name, r.ParentID }).Distinct();

        return Json(retValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the broken one's back end is querying the same table, except with the appropriate names switched around to get the other columns.

I've checked the database and I don't have any duplicate entries that might confuse it. When looking at other answers for this problem, none of them seemed to address this specific kind of problem. There are no errors being thrown inside of Visual Studio 2013 or the Chrome console when I attempt to get a response from the autocomplete.

I tried adding another form around the area to see if something strange was needing to be triggered in order to work and that did nothing.

Am I needing to add that @section around my scripts now? Or am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Your broken one is calling the `LookupFOOCT()` method - does it exist?

Comment: Yes, that method exists in the controller. There are absolutely no errors that are popping up in the consoles, Visual Studio or Chrome. Unless there is an invisible error that isn't showing up in bold red letters in the console, I have not seen any.

Comment: For anyone reading this later, as my project progressed, I changed all of the autocompletes to comboboxes. It is likely I won't return to this issue again to try and solve it. I'm sorry to anyone who was hoping for a solution to this :(